# How do matplotlib interactive navigation keyboard shortcuts work?

Tags: matplotlib, keyboard, shortcut, pan, zoom-sdk

I'd like to be able to zoom in on my figures without using the toolbar. I see keyboard shortcuts are listed here: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/users/navigation_toolbar.html

I tried it on a very simple example plot (I'm using Spyder IDE):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

But when I try the keyboard shortcuts on the figure, nothing happens. For example, holding down the letter "p" (for panning) while clicking and dragging my mouse pointer on the plot.